# Can I avoid getView() calls when measuring a GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview

In my `Activity` I have a `GridView` inflated from this XML layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/thumbnail_size"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="16dp" />
```

The items inside it are `RelativeLayout`s, each set to a fixed height. While profiling my `Activity`, I noticed that when I enter an `ActionMode`, it causes a measure pass, which causes the `GridView` to be re-measured. The `GridView` in turn calls `getView()` on my adapter many times to measure all of the child views. This is unnecessary work, since (a) which children are visible hasn't changed, so it already has all the views it needs; and (b) none of the child views can change size.

I know that `ListView` and `GridView` have lots of tricks they can do to avoid work in easy cases, and this seems like the kind of special case they might have an optimization for. Is there something I can set on the `GridView` to help it realise there's no need to call `getView()` again here? Alternatively, can I go higher up the stack and avoid the measure pass completely when entering and leaving an `ActionMode`? Just to be clear, the behaviour of my adapter is correct, and the `getView()` calls aren't causing me a problem: I just want my app to burn fewer cycles.

**N.B.** Even if I set the items to have fixed width as well as height, and replace the `GridView` with the following, it doesn't change the number of `getView()` calls (but it does make my `Activity` ugly).

```
<GridView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:verticalSpacing="16dp" />
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`? Since it needs to know how wide the columns are?

Comment: Since the views didn't change, and you know the tricks for getView, why does it even matter?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Because my getView is still quite complicated (and therefore slow): it has to check caches that can be updated from outside the Activity. I've made it as fast as I can, but I'd still like to reduce calls to it to reduce the latency of entering the ActionMode and to save battery use.

Comment: @DanHulme ok then, you've convinced me. added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ListView instead of GridView. Look at the implementation (API 16):

```
ListView.onMeasure(...) {
...
    if (mItemCount > 0 && (widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ||
            heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)) {
        final View child = obtainView(0, mIsScrap);
...
}
```

and

```
GridView.onMeasure(...) {
...
    final int count = mItemCount;
    if (count > 0) {
        final View child = obtainView(0, mIsScrap);
...
}
```

It looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for adding this information. I'm not yet convinced that it's a bug in GridView: after all, GridView has an extra degree of freedom when it comes to sizing (because it has columns, not just rows). Regardless, using ListView instead of GridView is not an option in this case: if it's unavoidable, as it seems, I'll just have to put up with it and optimize all I can.

Answer (score 2):

Some generic ways to make `GridView` perform better:

- Most important: Make your `getView()` as fast as possible. For example, move any IO or heavy computation away from UI thread.
- For measure/layout purposes, it seems that the view in position 0 is always requested. You can cache this view yourself to return it super fast in `getView()`.
- Get rid of any possible `LinearLayout`s with `layout_weight` as each nesting level there doubles the number of measure/layout passes required.

Answer (score 1):

how about the next solution:

add a flag in the adapter that once set, in the getView(), it will return the convertView without any changes.

if the user has touched the listView, set the flag to false.

if something has caused the listView to change its size (for example the actionMode) , set it to true.

EDIT: you will have to check that everything seems to be in order - that each view still shows the same item that it has shown before. it's not just "return the convertView". it depends on what has occurred.

Comment: Have you tested this idea, or is it a guess? There's no guarantee that the `convertView` previously showed the same list item, and it seems unlikely that GridView would do that while the old `View` for the item was still on the screen.

Comment: have you read my EDIT part? you need to use ViewHolder and hold the current position associated with the view in order to verify that it stayed the same. Please read the whole thing again.

Comment: I understand that, but if it never or rarely calls getView() with the same item's view as `convertView`, I haven't saved any time this way, I've just made my `getView()` slower for no reason. I've just tested, though, and it turns out that this is *not* the case. The `convertView` is often the right one, and in the action mode case it's *always* the right one.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it does avoid the expensive part of my `getView()`. I'd still prefer it if I could convince the `GridView` not to call `getView()` at all in such cases.

Comment: @DanHulme i don't understand your claim, and i don't think you've used the viewHolder paradigm for saving the item's index as i've suggested. i recommend that you show your code so that i can check it out. about not calling getView, i don't think it's logical as you do change the size of the gridview, so it needs to know what to do with its views. if you wish, you can use your own view on top of the gridView, so that it won't cause any resizing and therefore no calls for getView, but it will cause some overdraw issues.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Before I tried it, I was worried that the `convertView` would usually or always be from a different item, so it wouldn't be able to reuse it. The check would mean the behaviour was still correct, but it would usually or always take the slow path in `getView()`. I did try it, and it turned out that that *isn't* the case: the saved index shows that `convertView` is usually from the same item.

Comment: @DanHulme ok, if you say that you've figured it out... as i've written, you can avoid the calls to getView() if you put whatever view that causes it to resize itself to be on top of it.